# How to remove searchable dropdown default padding in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

Hello this is my flutter [widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoTc8.png) SearchableDropdown, and it is wrapped using a container just for highlighting the border for understanding how much space the widget have been taken.
I want to reduce the padding/space of the SearchableDropdown widget around the text, and make the UI [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBc7b.png) How to do that?

```
new Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    new Text(
                      'You are here',
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          color: HexColor("#B8B8B8"), fontSize: 10),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    ),
                    new Container(
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
                      ),
                      child: _searchableDropDown(context, providerData),
                    )
                  ],
                ),



 Widget _searchableDropDown(BuildContext context, HomePageProviderData data) {
  return new SearchableDropdown.single(
    hint: new Text(
      data.currentCity,
      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
        textStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xFF373539),
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
      ),
    ),
    underline: SizedBox(),
    displayClearIcon: false,
    items: data.listCity.map((item) {
    //
    }).toList(),
    onChanged: (String value) {
      //
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

try use wrapping your dropdown inside `SizedBox()` like this :

```
SizedBox(
  height: 20,
  child: _searchableDropDown(context, providerData),
);
```

result:

[image: result]

Comment: In my case, it's not working. when I put the height of the SizedBox to 20, RenderFlex overflow error occurred. Then changed the height to 50. it's just increase the height of the SizedBox and the DropDown Widget still remain the same.